# Searching a pattern in String

Tags: java, regex, search

I have one string object which contain multiple words.
From this String I need to find a 10 values Alpha-Numeric value which is in capital letters.

The pattern can vary like It can be other 10 Values (Which contain any Character and Digit)

EX:

My Name is batman. I am B012HIOL8L.

OutPut: B012HIOL8L

Comment: I am using java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this `/[A-Z0-9]{10}/` RegEx to match alpha-numeric substring that is exactly 10 characters in length.

Here is a sample implementation in JavaScript.

```
var string = "My Name is batman. I am B012HIOL8L.";
var match = string.match(/[A-Z0-9]{10}/);
console.log(match[0]);
```

In Java, you can use the same regular expression and use the [Java Regex API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/package-summary.html) to find the match. See the code below.

```
import java.util.regex.*;
class RegexTest {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    String string = "My Name is batman. I am B012HIOL8L.";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[A-Z0-9]{10}");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(string);
    while (m.find()) {
      System.out.println(m.group());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: May I have this in java.

Comment: @Anki In java you can use the same regex. I have added an example.

Answer (score 0):

You said :

> The pattern can vary like It can be other 10 Values (Which contain any
>   Character and Digit)

So You have to write `regex` that match any `Characters` between `[A-Z]` or `[0-9]` 10 times respectively, you can use this [A-Z0-9]{10} or ([A-Z]|[0-9]){10}.

```
    String string = "My Name is batman. I am B012HIOL8L.";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[A-Z0-9]{10}");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(string);
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group());
    }
```

please read this Article for more info [numeric ranges](https://www.regular-expressions.info/numericranges.html)